# Get request parameters and post

Tags: javascript, html, post

The following HTML page should get request parameters passed and call with post params but it does not seem to be working.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Processing</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');                        
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
}

function post() {    
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");;
    form.setAttribute("action", "https://demo.bank.com/B001/path");

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="post();">

</body>
</html>
```

Have I done anything wrong or is there any other way to do what I want to do?

Comment: `params` is not defined at line 24, In browser press **F12** and move to `console` to see errors in your script.

Comment: @nmnsud Thanks. I forgot to save the file before posting it to the web server.